# TypeScript either or return type is not detecting properties

Tags: javascript, typescript, return-type, either

```
type MyReturnType = Promise<boolean> | void

interface TestInterface {
    testFunction(): MyReturnType;
}

class TestClass implements TestInterface {
    testFunction() {
    }
}

const testObject = new TestClass();
testObject.testFunction()
    .then(() => { });
```

Why does it through the following error?

```
Property 'then' does not exist on type 'void'.
```

Am I missing something?

Comment: You defined `MyReturnType` to be either a `Promise<boolean>` or `void`.
So, according to that, it could be that you call to `void.then`, which is absurd.

Comment: Not sure what the problem is. Your code won't work (calling `undefined.then(…)`), and TypeScript correctly complains about that at compile time. Did you try running the code? What do you want to achieve?

Comment: I want the function testFunction() to return Promise or void based on certain conditions.  Sometimes, I get the return type as Promise, sometimes void.

Answer (score 0):

When you use the Union Type (denoted by the pipe character, '|'), you cannot assume the `testFunction` will return one type or another.

First you must check what type the `testFunction` returns after it has been called.

```
const result = testObject.testFunction()
if (result instanceof Promise) {
    result.then(() => {});
}
```

Comment: That's a fair point. Let me see if I can rewrite this.